# Android.mk in NDK file flags

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have a large C/C++ library that compiles on XCode but it does not compile on Eclipse using the Android NDK.
I have done a lot of research and searches on SO about this error for 2 days now, and none of the existing answers seem to help.

The current error message is:

```
error: undefined reference to ...
```

This error repeats for multiple classes, even though they all exist.

In Xcode this is compiling for Mac OS platform using LLVM 6.0 with just 2 compiler flags:

```
Apple LLVM 6.0 C Language Dialect: C99[-std=c99]
Apple LLVM 6.0 C++ Standard library: libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)
```

My Android is currently setup like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := com.LibAndroidBridge
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Class.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/...several

#LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -x c++
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_PTHREADS
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  += -std=c++11
#LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  += -std=c99

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -latomic

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And my Application.mk file is currently setup like this:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS+= -std=gnu++0x

#APP_ABI := all

APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti

#APP_CFLAGS += -std=c99

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:=4.8
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Any suggestions on how to make this large amount of code compile on Android?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly the undefined reference is for. If that is some of your code, you are probably missing some file in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`. If that is some library, you need to add it to `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` (you would need Android version though).

Comment: I am pointing to the folders in the LOCAL_SRC_FILES, and I have added all of their subfolders as well.
Some of the issues (at least removes a problem and brings a new one) get solved is I include the .cpp version of the file aside from just the header.
I'm not sure if this is even a good idea since the purpose of this is to re-use the library, but since this has over 3800 files I haven't even fully pursuit this idea.
Any idea why it doesn't just compile like it does on XCode?

Comment: If you want to use the library, you need to compile it for Android and then specify it in `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: well that's what I'm trying to do though, but it doesnt compile

Comment: Also note that `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` lists files, not folders. If you put folders there, it won't compile anything.

Comment: I have them like this in my Android.mk: 

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/Library/Json

Comment: This adds only search path for headers, it does not link or compile it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70665/discussion-between-toomanyeduardos-and-stensoft).

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're suggesting

Comment: by the way, this didn't work. Thank you for the suggestion though